# Can I link facebook's post when I make my page?

Tags: html

I have a question about html5 coding.

I want to link facebook page's newest post in my page.

For example, if there is a facebook page named "stackoverflow" and the page's newest post is "HTML5 question".

I want to take this "HTML5 question" post on my page, as it is.

After the newest post chages, on my page, it also changes.

Can I make it??

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Take a look at [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to simply link to your facebook page. The newest post is always shown on top there.

Comment: I can link it by hyperlink. But, I don't wanna link my facebook page by hyperlink. I want to see the newest post on my page. Can I do this?